# How to find closest words in a string in Python

Tags: python, match, scrape, closest

I am scraping the text of a long document with the same ticker repeated multiple times throughout. I am trying to locate a specific ticker that is closest to another word (let's call it a base word. Here is an example of the code:

```
ticker = 'TRBCX'
base_word = goal

string = 'TRBCX fund is up 2% today. TRBCX investment goal is to beat the S&P 500. TRBCX is managed by investment manager John Smith'
```

I am trying to find a way to grab the text around/between the second TRBCX and the base word "goal". So basically I want to grab a phrase that looks like this and give it a name:

```
''' code to find words around  ticker and baseword ''' = identifier
print(identifier)
output: 'TRBCX investment goal' or 'today. TRBCX investment goal is'
```

I will use the chunk of text (identifier) to identify a new section. The location of the ticker that I am interested in is different every time. Thank you so much for your help. I know this might seem confusing.

Comment: A very brute force approach would be to run a levenshtein distance for each word in your string and order it from smallest to largest.

Comment: [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) seems to be the defacto for this until you get into larger projects or specific needs then [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/index.html) may be your goto depending on the project needs. But these are only 2 libraries out of several. Maybe checking out [Awesome Python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#natural-language-processing) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be using Levenshtein distance which allows us to compare strings and find how similar they are. This would allow you to find which words are closest to each other with an object metric.

Based on your example:

```
!pip install python-Levenshtein
from Levenshtein import distance as lev
ticker = 'TRBCX'
string = 'TRBCX fund is up 2% today. TRBCX investment goal is to beat the S&P 500. TRBCX is managed by investment manager John Smith'
distances = {key:lev(ticker,key) for key in string.split()}
```

Returns:

```
{'2%': 5,
 '500.': 5,
 'John': 5,
 'S&P': 5,
 'Smith': 5,
 'TRBCX': 0,
 'beat': 5,
 'by': 5,
 'fund': 5,
 'goal': 5,
 'investment': 10,
 'is': 5,
 'managed': 7,
 'manager': 7,
 'the': 5,
 'to': 5,
 'today.': 6,
 'up': 5}
```